# How to use @Inject and get the instance of the service not in the constructor?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a generic class that uses http inside it:

```
export abstract class GenericCrudService<T> {
  constructor(protected http: HttpService, protected resourse: Resourse) {}

  private entities: T[] = [];
  entitiesChanged$: Subject<T[]> = new Subject();

  getAllEntities() {
    this.http.get<T>(environment.endpoint + this.resourse).subscribe((res) => {
      this.entities = res;
      this.entitiesChanged$.next(this.entities);
    });
  }

  createEntity(entity: T) {
    return this.http
      .post(environment.endpoint + this.resourse, entity)
      .subscribe((_) => {
        this.entities.push(entity);
        this.entitiesChanged$.next(this.entities);
      });
  }
  deleteEntity(id: string) {
    return this.http
      .delete(environment.endpoint + this.resourse, id)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.entities = this.entities.filter((e: any) => e._id !== res.deleted);
        this.entitiesChanged$.next(this.entities);
      });
  }

  updateEntity(id: string, newEntity: T) {
    return this.http
      .put(environment.endpoint + this.resourse, id, newEntity)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        const updatedIndex = this.entities.findIndex(
          (e: any) => e._id === res.updated
        );
        this.entities[updatedIndex] = newEntity;
        this.entitiesChanged$.next(this.entities);
      });
  }

  getLatestEntities() {
    return this.entitiesChanged$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

also have this service that extends that class:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ExerciseService extends GenericCrudService<IExercise> {
  constructor(http: HttpService) {
    super(http, Resourse.exercise);
  }
}
```

I thought it would be nicer to not inject the http client in the exercise service as it doesnt need it, and create it only in the generic one by doing something like:

@Inject(HTTP_TOKEN?) http : HttpService
and use this.http everywhere in the service. My question is, is it possible and recommended and also if so how can I get the HttpService injection token, or how can I create one if it doesnt exist?

Comment: JFYI: `resourse = Resourse.exercise;` line is redundant, as it is already done in parent. in your version the "assigning" logic is just got duplicated.

Comment: is it was by mistake

Comment: @Andrei so what is your suggestion for refactoring in this code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is only one "elegant" way to inject anything in Angular and that is the constructor way. The other way is to inject Injector in the constructor and Injector.get(token) at any moment of runtime.

```
myService = this.injector.get(MyService);
constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
```

in your code it would be

```
export abstract class GenericCrudService<T> {
  protected http = this.injector.get(HttpService);
  constructor(protected injector: Injector, protected resourse: Resourse) {}
...
}
....
export class ExerciseService extends GenericCrudService<IExercise> {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    super(injector, Resourse.exercise);
  }
}
```

then in any descendants you would only pass the injector to parent, and parent may inject whatever it wants with the help of this injector

UPDATE:
it is no longer necessary to inject the `Injector` to query all of the dependencies without using constructor. From Angular 14 there is an `inject` global function exposed

```
class SomeComponent {
  myService = inject(MyService);
  ...
```

Comment: so it's a better practice to do it like I did than @Inject(HTTP_TOKEN?) http : HttpService in the service? What if I extended more than two levels? Do you think it is right to pass the dependencies like that ?

Comment: you could make use of angular DI if the discussion was about components, because they have component level injectors. it would be possible to `@Component({... providers: [provide: Resource, useValue: Resource.excercise]}) class MyClass {}`; but it is a pity that services can't do that. If you have plans for multi level inheritance, then I would use Injector in the constructor and then inject anything that needed in parent. It is better in case you would like to add dependencies at one of "parent" levels. no other updates than 1 class would be required.

Comment: Can you show me how this is implemented in my code please?

Comment: Thanks for your help 